# Перевод проекта на Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

У меня возникла внутреннее желание попробовать перевести мой проект на Spring Boot так как он намного удобнее.

Сам проект Spring MVC. Использую JSP, PostgresDB, application.xml и тд(в планах перевести xml на Java Config). Так как в Spring Boot никогда не работал, обращаюсь к знатокам.

На сколько проблематично мне перевести мой проект на Spring Boot, знаю что надо некоторые зависимости прописать в pom'е ну и создать стартующий класс с аннотацией, но и понимаю, что сделав это, у меня проект не запустится так сразу.

Плюс еще, нужно ли мне переписывать мои каталоги, на templates и static?
Понимаю, что вопрос может быть глупым, но все равно, на то они и вопросы )

Comment: Boot - это просто автонастройщик и запускальщик. Если действительно понимаете Spring, то добавление Boot к MVC потребует минимальных усилий.

Comment: спасибо большое Сергей, тогда буду разбираться с ним.

Comment: @Владислав может сами тогда ответите на свой вопрос)) а то порой гугл отправляет на ваш вопрос))